# Where to use scrollToRowAtIndexPath in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am using `[self.messageList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];` in cellForRowAtIndexPath and it is working fine, when a row is added in table array then it auto scroll upside but the problem is that when I try to see the top rows then it automatically come again last rows. And I am not able to see my all rows. Please let me know where I use this or any other approach to do this.

Comment: Post you code first so that problem can be determined

Answer (score 1):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not called for all cell that you have. It is only called for visible cell in your TableView. When You Scroll `UITableView` then it ask to `UITableView` that you want to use reusable cell or add to new one. generally we use reusable cell so, it is use 1st no of cell and add  at end of cell . it is not create another new cell at the end. so, when you scroll your `UITableView` it not scroll to end of cell it `indexPath` is similar to `indexPath` of first no of cell. so you can not scroll your `UITableView` at to Down.

**use following code may be helpful for you.... :)**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            [self.tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated: YES];
           // your code 

        }

          // your code 

        return cell;    

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write this code in your cell for row at index path, then it will get called every time you try to scroll manually coz this message is called to draw your cell and you will b directed to the row you specified. Try checking your indexpath in a IF--Else block and scroll only when a certain action happens.

Comment: ya I have try for it trough this code if([self tableView:self.messageList numberOfRowsInSection:
            index_old.section] > indexPath.row){
            [self.messageList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
        
        }
but what I'll assign first time in index_old.

Comment: what is it exactly that you want to achieve.. i mean what behavior do you want in you table view?

Comment: In this table dynamically added the data from web service so I want that last row which is added is shown at the front of user or upside rows go upside 1 step.

Comment: you can use something like this, [yourTableView beginUpdates]; [yourTableView insertRowAtIndexPath:UITableViewCellAnimation]; [yourTableView endUpdates]; using this you can insert data any where, in your case the top row I believe, then you can scroll the table view to that indexpath. I hope It helps you..

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a method for creating a cell to view .When you scroll this method is called when a cell is viewed.So each time the method called the  `[self.messageList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`  method(which is called inside `cellForRow`) is also called and the table scrolls down to that row!!!

Comment: Ya I know thats why I asking that where I'll use this code. or any other idea to do this.

Comment: @user1652551 what is your purpose to scroll to certain row??

Comment: In this table dynamically added the data from web service so I want that last row which is added is shown at the front of user or upside rows go upside 1 step.

Comment: @user1652551 : K then how are you updating the table? You can call this scrolling method there